# Port and IP in Podio API?

Tags: podio

So we have this client who asked us to create a Simple Form that will create an item in Podio. Problem is they are very strict in security and before we can upload the created form to their server, they are asking us to provide some sort IP and Port. Now, I am not sure what Port and IP they are referring.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

All requests to the API should be port 443 because we use HTTPS.

For more information please see our developers guide. [1]

[1] https://developers.podio.com/